# Can we use the phrase "get pleasure" without using "out of" or "from" along with it?

Tags: sentence-choice

Let's say somebody asked, *"How was the movie?"*, after I went to the movies. Can I say to him, *"It was nice. I got pleasure"*, or do I have to say, *"I got pleasure out of it/from it"* instead of just saying "I got pleasure." I mean, I wonder if we can generally say just "get pleasure" instead of "get pleasure out of/from something." I needed to ask this question because I couldn't find a usage of "get pleasure" without "out of/from" in any dictionaries.

Another example: Can I say, *"I get a lot of pleasure playing video games with him"* instead of *"I get a lot of pleasure out of/from playing video games with him"*?

Comment: The idiomatic thing to say is "I **enjoyed it**." "Pleasure" sounds odd here no matter how you package it.

Comment: @TypeIA Thanks. Do you think the structure in the sentences I gave is grammatical though?

Comment: The _structure_ is fine, but we never say "get pleasure" by itself. It's always "to get (or derive) pleasure **from**" or "... **out of**" something or "to **take** pleasure **in**" something. You can also say "to be pleased" with no object ("I am pleased.") But all of these sound out of place here, which is why I suggested "I enjoyed it."

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, although grammatical, it is not at all idiomatic to say "I got pleasure from that movie". There are far more natural way to say that you enjoyed something, or found it fun.

To answer your question directly though, yes, you can say "that movie gave me pleasure", or "video games give me pleasure. There is no need to use the word "from" in the way your examples do. Either way, it still sounds a bit formal and unnatural.

You *can* use 'pleasure' as a *verb*, and that avoids using the words you are asking about, for example, "*that movie pleasured me*". However, as a verb, the word has fallen from everyday use somewhat and to most English speakers it only has seedy, sexual connotations. I would not use it to say I enjoyed a movie.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew that we could use the phrase "give pleasure", so you say we can also use "get pleasure" without "out of/from", right? You used "give" in your examples.